# Trigger mail automatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have developed a .NET application with a SQL database. In SQL I have table `Table_dom` which contains a `Date` column where I will store date. Another table is `Table_TL` where I have one `email` column.

Now when the date is 5 days after the current date I need to send a reminder mail to `TL` from the `Table_TL` table `email` column. Could you please help on this?

Thank you.

Comment: How are the two tables connected?

Comment: I have Tower field which will be comman to two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL Server 2005 or later you could use the [Database Mail feature](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/SQLServer/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_20.shtml) to send emails directly from the database. A periodic check for sending reminders could be setup using a [SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).

**Edit:**

Provided you have setup the Database Mail correctly you should be able to add something like this (untested) to a SQL job:

```
DECLARE @recipient AS varchar(255)   
DECLARE users CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT tl.email 
    FROM Table_TL tl 
    INNER JOIN Table_dom dom ON tl.thekey = dom.thekey
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, dom.date, GETDATE()) > 5

OPEN users
FETCH NEXT FROM users INTO @recipient
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'The profile you set up for the mail feature'
      , @recipients = @recipient
      , @subject = 'The subject'
      , @body = 'The message'

    FETCH NEXT FROM users INTO @recipient
END
CLOSE users 
DEALLOCATE users
```

Comment: I need sample query to trigger mail from taking mail from tables